# How to do conditional "withColumn" in a Spark dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe (mydf) as follows:

```
+---+---+---+---+
| F1| F2| F3| F4|
+---+---+---+---+
|  t| y4|  5|1.0|
|  x|  y|  1|0.5|
|  x|  y|  1|0.5|
|  x|  z|  2|1.0|
|  x|  b|  5|1.0|
|  t| y2|  6|1.0|
|  t| y3|  3|1.0|
|  x|  a|  4|1.0|
+---+---+---+---+
```

I want to do a conditional aggregation inside "`withColumn`" as follows:

```
mydf.withColumn("myVar", if($"F3" > 3) sum($"F4") else 0.0)
```

that is for every row having `$F3 <= 0` , `myVar` should have a value of 0.0 and others sum of `$"F4"`.

How to achieve it in Spark Scala?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the function `when` to use conditionals

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.when
mydf.withColumn("myVar", when($"F3" > 3, $"F4").otherwise(0.0))
```

But I don't get what do you want to sum, since there is a single value of F4 by row

**EDIT**
If you want to aggregate first you can perform a `groupBy` and and `agg` as follows:

```
mydf.groupBy("F1", "F2")
.agg(sum("F3").as("F3"), sum("F4").as("F4"))
```

And then add the withColumn sentence just as before.

Putting all together
:

```
   mydf.groupBy("F1", "F2")
    .agg(sum("F3").as("F3"), sum("F4").as("F4"))
    .withColumn("myVar", when($"F3" > 3, $"F4").otherwise(0.0))
```

Comment: hey, what does the $ do in this function? does it remove the need to wrap the column with col()?

Comment: Right, $"something" is a way to access a column, just the same as col(something)